# How to count number of sentences in a string?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that counts the number of sentences in a string. 
I count the number of '.' '?' '!'. However, there are Mr. Mrs. PhD. Dr. ..... situations. Any help please?

```
int number_of_sentences = 0;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i <= text.length()-1; i++){
    if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' ||text[i] == '!'){
      ++number_of_sentences;
    }
  }
  return number_of_sentences;
```

Comment: Add exceptions for these words. Done.

Comment: The text I need to read is very long, these words are just example. There are bunch of abbreviations in the text that I couldn't list here.

Comment: "Any help please?" is not a concise question. This isn't a pair programming service.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it. You would need a full natural language parser to handle it with any accuracy.

Discarding the words you mention won't solve the problem. Consider:

> I am impressed by that PhD. James was awarded.
>
> I am impressed by that PhD. James was awarded it in 2001.

It is only your understanding of the semantics of English that tells you that the first one is one sentence and the second one is two sentences. You wouldn't be able to tell the difference without thinking about the *meaning* of the words, though. You are trying to solve the problem at the purely syntactic level, but there isn't enough information in the text without considering semantics.

The best approximation would probably be to say that you get a new sentence whenever you get a ".", "!" or "?" and the next word starts with a capital letter. But this would still be only approximately correct. It would get the first of these examples wrong, and the second one right.

Comment: It would also fail on most Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Why don't you split the string in token? Then countdown every time there is a word as Mrs., Mr. ect..

Or replacing special words with white space then counting without problem.

```cpp
std::string RemoveWords(const std::string& source, const std::string& chars) {
    std::string result="";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<source.length(); i++) {
      bool foundany=false;
      for (unsigned int j=0; j<chars.length() && !foundany; j++) {
        foundany=(source[i]==chars[j]);
      }
      if (!foundany) {
        result+=source[i];
      }
    }
   return result;
}

int number_of_sentences = 0;
text = RemoveWords(text);
for(unsigned int i=0; i <= text.length()-1; i++){
  if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' ||text[i] == '!'){
  ++number_of_sentences;
  }
}
return number_of_sentences;
```

The above solution will omit every character passed in the second argument string. For example:

```
std::string result=RemoveWords("Mrs. Rease will play to football. ByeBye", "Mrs.");
```

Comment: As a hint for future posts: You don't have to post incomplete answers or questions to _save them_. Draft versions are saved automatically by the system.